# Property does not exist on type 'MyObject' - Typescript extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, typescript2.0

I created a basic extension on the Date object, and it works fine. Below is my CODE:

**date.extensions.ts**

```
export {}

declare global {
    interface Date {
        toSQLiteString(): string;
    }
}

Date.prototype.toSQLiteString = function() {
    let tzo = -this.getTimezoneOffset();
    let dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
    let pad = function(num) {
        let norm = Math.abs(Math.floor(num));
        return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
    };

    return this.getFullYear() +
        '-' + pad(this.getMonth() + 1) +
        '-' + pad(this.getDate()) +
        'T' + pad(this.getHours()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getMinutes()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getSeconds()) +
        dif + pad(tzo / 60) +
        ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
};
```

Now, I want to create an extension file on a custom object, lets call it *MyModel*.  This object is defined in another file and looks like so (very simple example)

```
export class MyObject {
    id: number = 0;
    name: string = ''
}
```

Now i want to create a file called *MyObject.extensions.ts* and have an extension function, so i have created this and the file looks like so

```
import { MyObject } from './my-object.ts'

export {}

declare global {
    interface MyObject {
        getIdAndName(): string;
    }
}

MyObject.prototype.getIdAndName = function() {
    return this.id + ' - ' + this.name;
};
```

But, for some reason I am am getting an error by typescript

[image]

If however, i remove the `import` at the top of the file, the error disappears, but i get a different error, as below

[image]

I am using typescript 2.4.2

Any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: You probably will do with giving different names to the Interface and class. You can't modify types. Your class is a value and can be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is not in the global namespace it is in a module, you should extend the module declaration :

```
import { MyObject } from './my-object'

export {}

declare module './my-object' {
    interface MyObject {
        getIdAndName(): string;
    }
}

MyObject.prototype.getIdAndName = function() {
    return this.id + ' - ' + this.name;
};
```

Also remove the `.ts` extension from your module import.

Comment: This works thank you.  Although do you know if you can extend an object and get the extensions that are declared on the base object to work? Although this compiles, when i run it it says that the "new" object doesnt have the function... when it is declared on the base object

Comment: @Gillardo sorry for the late answer, say your new question I replied there